# Replace the first character of every element with “$” and add “_” at the end of every element present in the list

Tags: python

I was able to do it by looping accessing `list[i][j]`.
 but wanted to do it without looping.
Any ideas how to do it

Example list :

Input:  `["abc","def","ghi"]`

Output: `["$bc_","$ef_","$hi_"]`

Comment: Why do you need a `j` loop? Just one loop for the list elements, and concatenate the strings.

Comment: `['$'+s[1:]+'_' for s in mylist]` Although that's *still* a loop.

Comment: You absolutely need a loop.  It's either a `for` loop or a `for` clause in a list comprehension

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension and concatenate or format the strings you want.

```
inlist = ['abc','def','ghi']
outlist = [f'${s[1:]}_' for s in inlist]
```

Comment: Careful! `in` is a build-in. This code will not work. You will get a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks. I was careful not to call it `input` :)

Comment: looks better now, but now the next answer is using build-ins, have to go :-)

Comment: the syntax is not correct here because the `f-string` has not been called properly which leaves a dangling open `{`

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
lstIn = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
lstOut = [f'${i[1:]}_' for i in lstIn] 
print(lstOut)
```

Prints:

```
['$bc_', '$ef_', '$hi_']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
lst = ["abc","def","ghi"]
out = [ "".join(("$",s[1:],"_")) for s in lst ]
```

Output: `print(out)`

```
['$bc_', '$ef_', '$hi_']
```

Comment: Careful! `list` is a build-in!

Comment: using `join` over `f-strings` when building variables is significantly slower

Comment: Why do you need to use `.join()`? Just `print([('$'+s[1:]+'_') for s in lst])`